# How To Display these Query

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sqlite

How Display All Employees First_name and Last_name from [Tbl_Employee] For 
eg:

```
 First_name   Last_Name    Display
 Abhi         Kulshrestha  A K
```

Comment: Display where...?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'as' for creating the header of the column like below and can concatenate string with column value like below.

```
  SELECT top 1 'First_name : '+Firstname AS 'First_name',
           'Last_Name: '+Lastname AS 'Last_name',
           'Display: '+ left(isnull(Firstname,'.'),1) + ' ' + left(isnull(Lastname,'.'),1) AS 'Display'
FROM [Tbl_Employee]
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged both sql-server and sqllite, which is it?

sql server:

```
select 
    FirstName
  , LastName
  , isnull(left(FirstName,1)+' ','') + isnull(left(LastName,1),'') as Display
from [Tbl_Employee]
```

sqllite:

```
select 
    FirstName
  , LastName
  , substr(Lastname1,1,) || ' ' ||substr(FirstName,1,1) as Display
from [Tbl_Employee]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select left(isnull(First_name,'.'),1) + ' ' + left(isnull(Last_name,'.'),1) from  Tbl_Employee
```

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mean to edit your answer, I was trying to post my own.

Comment: @SqlZim no problems

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.